# How can I get the position of the cursor/caret within an HTML input element?

Tags: javascript

Should be pretty simple, but I can't seem to find it in Google.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `selectionStart` or `selectionEnd` property of the `input` element.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  console.log([document.getElementById("test").selectionStart, document.getElementById("test").

selectionEnd
------------

]);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test"></input>
```